# How can I identify numbers from an image?

Tags: python, ocr, image-recognition, number-recognition

I'm writing a script that takes an image and crops the image down to only include the number I want it to recognize. I have that part working fine. The numbers will be either single or double digit.

I've tried using Googles Vision API, which works fine and gives the correct result, but I would rather do it locally to avoid the fees associated with using that service. I'm currently working on using Tesseract OCR https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract

Example of an image I want it to recognize:

[image]

Tesseract is a command line program but I am calling it in a python file that also handles the other parts of my script. I'm not sure if Tesseract is what I want or if there is a better solution to my problem.

```
sudo tesseract imgName outputFile
```

The only results I get no matter what image I put through it returns 0 and also shows "Empty page!!"

EDIT:

I am now using pytesseract and I am trying with this code:

```py
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
```

Nothing is outputted from that so I tried

```py
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img,config ='--psm 6'))
```

which outputs random letters it's guessing. Is there a way with tesseract to only look for numbers so my results are narrowed down?

Comment: Please edit into your question your current code and a sample image and show what you want/expect the output to be.

Comment: What research have you done - and why did that searching not get the results you wanted?

Comment: “Edit into your question your current code” I meant: please edit into your question a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - so people reading this question can copy/paste your example into a file and reproduce the exact same problem you are seeing, i.e. without editing/adding anything.

Comment: Python Library "pytesseract" is what you're looking for. Read your image through PIL or OpenCV and then pass it to the pytesseract method image_to_string to get the text out of it.

Comment: it may better works with black text on white background. See documentation: [Improving the quality of the output](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality)

Comment: I tried you image with Tesseract v4.0.0-beta.1 and it gives me `>3` in  `outputFile.txt` If you run it in Python with some subprocess functions and you get its result then you may get 0 as status code which means "OK" (no errors). Better use `pytesseract`.

Comment: When I try with pytesseract it outputs nothing just a blank line.

Comment: @jimmyshadow1 Post the code where you're trying with pytesseract

Comment: ```print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))```
img is to the path of my image. I also tried Image.open(img)